# Save as dialog using php/or html to fwrite in user choice

Tags: php, html, dialog, savefiledialog

My doubt is how to open a dialog box(using html/php) to the user so that he can decide where the txt file (which will be created by the php fwrite) will be recorded and under what name.

**update1:**

he page will get checkboxes with values, and i want the user to be able to give a directory and a nameOfFile to the php script so that the file will be created in that directory with that name, but i want something like a dialog box to user indicate where he decides that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP cannot write files on a clients system (PHP is a server side language).

I'm unaware of a save dialog functionality in html/javascript where the user could select a destination and a file will then download to that functionality.

Comment: The page will get checkboxes with values, and i want the user to be able to give a directory and a nameOfFile to the php script so that the file will be created in that directory with that name, but i want something like a dialog box to user indicate where he decides that.

Comment: @MichaelS - Please read the answer carefully and make sure you understand it