# Need a solution similar to 'Save as' dialog box to choose the file name and location using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, fwrite

I need to use fwrite function in php for storing a file at a location,  chosen by user.
I am just curious, if there is any way such that I can show some thing similar to 'save as' dialog box in javascript to choose the file name and the location to be saved, so that I can send this name to php and use it as argument to fwrite function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: saving file on server or user machine?

Comment: Add some more background to your question. Where is PHP running and what needs to be saved?

Comment: possible duplicate of, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847425/save-as-dialog-using-php-or-html-to-fwrite-in-user-choise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ajax to create something like that: Open a dialog, call php `scandir` to get directory structure, return it and draw in your dialog. Finally upload the file when user select a path.

You can DIY, or using a free 3rd party plugin like this http://ckfinder.com/demo

Comment: Thanks all for responding to my question. Actually I am a newbie in javascript/php. 

I was able to solve my problem by writing file to a fixed folder in server, and giving user a link after the file has been created in that directory.

Please excuse me, for my stupid question.